# SQL Server 2008 R2 limit processors available

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 running on a Windows Server 2008 R2.
The processor have 8 cores and when I do a big query or update, all server freezes, because all of my 8 processors are taken for this.
So I want the SQL Server to use only max 7 cores. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a query hint to limit the degree of parallelism for the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
OPTION(MAXDOP 7);
```

This can also be set at the server level for all queries with sp_configure:

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXECUTE sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 7;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```